# Why vsyscall is in 0xffffffffff600000-0xffffffffff601000, not user space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

vsyscall: kernel maps these system calls implementation and the related-data into user space pages.

So why vsyscall's address range is 0xffffffffff600000-0xffffffffff601000 (kernel space)?

Comment: because that's what the designers said. Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @user253751 I suppose it should be in the user space, that's to say, the address range that the first bit should be 0?

Comment: There's no rule that says it has to be.

Comment: Note that the kernel developers didn't like vsyscall very much, so they invented vDSO instead, which is in user space.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I know vsyscall is obsolete, but if it is located in kernel space, that means we still need context switches each time to call them, is that right?

Comment: no, it means the page 0xffffffffff600000-0xffffffffff601000 is user space. Well, it did mean that. Nowadays it's kernel space and the kernel is watching to see if the user mode accesses it and it emulates the call.

Comment: @user253751 So in the old days, kernel and user space separation is not determined by the first bit, right?

Comment: I don't think it ever was. The kernel just chooses to make it that way.